# CiviMail cron job unable to find: civicrm.config.php, built with: roundearth/drupal-civicrm-project

Tags: civimail, cron

My next issue is this:

attempts to push out a civilmailing result, as reported by /civicrm/admin/joblog, with this error: 
'API permission check failed for Group/get call', . . . 'insufficient permission: require access CiviCRM'

From my $drush_context path, I had run 
sudo -u www-data ../../../vendor/civicrm/cv/bin/cv api Job.execute
Same result without the sudo as www-data.

Full log entry:

```
Details

Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message: 

> Finished execution of Mailings scheduler with result: Failure, Error
> message:  API permission check failed for Group/get call; insufficient
> permission: require access CiviCRM
```

My build put the following in place:

```
# grep -v ^# /var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data 
*/5 * * * * /home/drupal/lib/sh/civimail_cron_job.sh process_mailing
*/15 * * * * /home/drupal/lib/sh/civimail_cron_job.sh fetch_bounces
```

Running that manually results in:

```
# sudo -u www-data /bin/bash /home/drupal/lib/sh/civimail_cron_job.sh process_mailing 
PHP Warning:  require_once(civicrm.config.php): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
in /opt/local/my_client/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/bin/cli.class.php on line 245

PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): 
Failed opening required 'civicrm.config.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') 
in /opt/local/my_client/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/bin/cli.class.php on line 245
```

closest I come to finding that file on this container is:

```
# locate civicrm.config.php 
/opt/local/my_client/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8/civicrm.config.php.drupal
/opt/local/my_client/drupal/web/modules/contrib/civicrm/civicrm.config.php.drupal
```

```
# drush user:information mailprocess 
 User ID       :  23                                       
 User name     :  mailprocess                              
 User mail     :  mailprocess@uat.db.georgiagreenparty.net 
 User roles    :  authenticated                            
                  civimail_role                            
 User status   :  1
```

```
# drush role:list civimail_role
 Permission        
 access CiviCRM    
 access CiviMail   
 view all contacts
```

**UPDATING this script's listing**

```
# cat /home/drupal/lib/sh/civimail_cron_job.sh 

#!/bin/bash

CMD=$1
CWD=/opt/local/my_client/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core
requirements='-d require ./web/core/includes/bootstrap.inc -d require ./web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Session/AccountInterface.php'
PHP="/usr/bin/nice -n19 /usr/bin/php ${requirements}"
PARAMS='-j -s default -u mailprocess -p asecretpassword -e Job -a '

cd $CWD; $PHP bin/cli.php $PARAMS $CMD

exit 0
```

**UPDATE**

```
l# CIVICRM_SETTINGS=`pwd`/web/sites/default/civicrm.settings.php /bin/bash ./civimail_cron_job.sh 
 + CMD=
 + CWD=/opt/local/my_client/drupal
 + requirements='-d require ./web/core/includes/bootstrap.inc -d require ./web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Session/AccountInterface.php'
 + PHP='/usr/bin/nice -n19 /usr/bin/php -d require ./web/core/includes/bootstrap.inc -d require ./web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Session/AccountInterface.php'
 + PARAMS='-j -s default -u mailprocess -p verysecret -e Job -a '
 + cd /opt/local/my_client/drupal
 + /usr/bin/nice -n19 /usr/bin/php -d require ./web/core/includes/bootstrap.inc  -d require ./web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Session/AccountInterface.php vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/bin/cli.php -j -s default -u mailprocess -p verysecret -e Job -a
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface' not found in /opt/local/my_client/drupal/web/core/includes/bootstrap.inc:106
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /opt/local/my_client/drupal/web/core/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 106
 + exit 0
```

or to highlight the issue, here:
**Uncaught Error: Class 'Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface' not found**

line 106 of bootstrap.inc, reads:

```
const DRUPAL_ANONYMOUS_RID = AccountInterface::ANONYMOUS_ROLE;
```

2,738 mentions of this function in the code base, 
not sure what more I must do to get my code to find it.

```
/opt/local/my_client/drupal# grep -R 'AccountInterface' . | wc -l
2738

/opt/local/my_client/drupal# grep -R 'AccountInterface' web/ | wc -l
1365
```

**Further UPDATE**

As for testing the use of cv here, running this:

```
# vendor/civicrm/cv/bin/cv api job.execute 
{
    "is_error": 0,
    "version": 3,
    "count": 1,
    "values": 1
}
```

is yielding the following in the logs at /civicrm/admin/joblog:

```
Date    Job Name    Command/Job Status/Additional Information
2020-06-01 01:32:26     
Summary
Finishing scheduled jobs execution.
2020-06-01 01:32:26 Mailings scheduler  
Entity: job Action: process_mailing
Summary
Finished execution of Mailings scheduler with result: Failure, Error message: API permission check failed for Group/get call; insufficient permission: require access CiviCRM
Details


Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message: 
Finished execution of Mailings scheduler with result: Failure, Error message: API permission check failed for Group/get call; insufficient permission: require access CiviCRM

2020-06-01 01:32:26 Mailings scheduler  
Entity: job Action: process_mailing
Summary
Starting execution of Mailings scheduler
Details


Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message: 
Starting execution of Mailings scheduler

2020-06-01 01:32:26     
Summary
Starting scheduled jobs execution
```

*leading me to wonder how it is I get cv to run with my mailprocess user, which has these missing permissions?*

**UPDATE #3**

Thank you, HomoTechsual, for the --user and --cwd switches.  
Had missed those.  
Now using this invocation:

```
/usr/bin/nice -n19 /usr/bin/php \
    -d require ./web/core/includes/bootstrap.inc \
    -d require ./web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Session/AccountInterface.php \
    /opt/local/my_client/drupal/vendor/civicrm/cv/bin/cv api job.execute \
    --cwd=/opt/local/my_client/drupal \
    --user=mailprocess
```

and getting this error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface' not found in /opt/local/my_client/drupal/web/core/includes/bootstrap.inc:106
```

**UPDATE #4**

This invocation now returns a result code of 0.
And still I see no evidence that it ran my civimail,
in the browser UI, at /civicrm/mailing/browse/unscheduled,
nor in the logs at /civicrm/admin/joblog.

```
/usr/bin/nice -n19 /usr/bin/php \
    -d require /opt/local/my_client/drupal/vendor/autoload.php \
    /opt/local/ggp_crm/drupal/vendor/civicrm/cv/bin/cv api job.execute \
    --cwd=/opt/local/ggp_crm/drupal --user=mailprocess
```

My script now reads:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

CMD=$1
CWD='/opt/local/my_client/drupal'
CV="${CWD}/vendor/civicrm/cv/bin/cv"
CIVIMAIL_USER='mailprocess'
requirements="-d require ${CWD}/vendor/autoload.php"
PHP="/usr/bin/nice -n19 /usr/bin/php"
ARGS="--cwd=${CWD} --user=${CIVIMAIL_USER}"

cd ${CWD}; ${PHP} ${requirements} ${CV} api job.execute ${ARGS}
exit "$?"
```

Comment: Can you try having that script run from `/opt/local/my_client/drupal/` as the CWD rather than `/opt/local/my_client/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core`.

Also. for what it's worth - you'll find [CV](https://github.com/civicrm/cv) much more useful for cron-jobs on Drupal 8/9 than cli.php which hasn't really been updated to work with D8 or D9 which are not yet officially supported.

Comment: To get CV to run as a specific user add `--user=USERNAME` to the end (as covered in the docs).

Answer (score 3):

You should run CV commands from the root of the website (especially on Drupal 8/9 - where support isn't as well tested for "pathing" - i.e finding the correct files to bootstrap CiviCRM).

If your website lives in `/var/www/civicrm` that's the directory you should be in when running CV commands (ideally!). You may find that being in `/var/www/civicrm/web` or `/var/www/civicrm/web/modules` works but chances are it'll confuse the pathfinding logic!

To run commands as a specific user you should append `--user=USERNAME` to the end of the command string.

To run commands via cron you should use the absolute path to CV, your site and PHP.

**For example:**

`/usr/bin/php /usr/local/bin/cv api job.execute --cwd=/var/www/civicrm --user=admin`

Comment: Thank you for the --user and --cwd switches.  Had missed those.  
Now using this invocation:  

`/usr/bin/nice -n19 /usr/bin/php -d require ./web/core/includes/bootstrap.inc -d require ./web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Session/AccountInterface.php /opt/local/my_client/drupal/vendor/civicrm/cv/bin/cv api job.execute --cwd=/opt/local/my_client/drupal --user=mailprocess` 

and getting this error message:  

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface' not found in /opt/local/my_client/drupal/web/core/includes/bootstrap.inc:106`.

Comment: I have also tested, with no joy, but the exact same error message, several variations on this:  `-d includepath=/opt/local/my_client/drupal/web/core/lib`

Comment: May have just discovered the secret sauce!  Further testing required, but I got not error messages and `echo $?` returns 0.  I used this on the cli:  `-d require ./vendor/autoload.php`.